# Laravel API DB transaction with too long code. How do I modularize or optimize this code? (I am new to Laravel)

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, laravel-api

I have very complex functions in laravel APIs ( called from Mobile App).
The sample function is given below.
If someone can help to improve the code structure.
I wish to know the best practices in handling multiple transactions in a single API. Because if I move each table's entry to separate function - how do I handle errors of each one? Ex: when the quantity is not set in $request model

SUMMARY:
**Can someone please break it into smaller functions?**
....   **Because I don't know how/where to break it into smaller ones.**

```
    public function placeOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'addressId' => 'required'
        ]);
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $itemList = array();
        $deliveryCharge = Store::first()->delivery_charge;
        // $deliveryCharge = Store::findOrFail($request->header('StoreId'))->delivery_charge;
        $total = $deliveryCharge;
        $cod = $request->cod;
        $useBalanceFirst = $request->useBalanceFirst;
        $addressId = $request->addressId;
        $list = $request->list;
        $cost = 0;
        // fetch all items using id in request
        foreach ($list as $orderItemFromRequest) {


            if (!isset($orderItemFromRequest['id']))
                return $this->error("Invalid item selected");

            $itemFromDB = Item::find($orderItemFromRequest['id']);

            if (!isset($orderItemFromRequest['quantity']))
                return $this->error("Please enter quantity for {$itemFromDB->name}");

            $qty = $orderItemFromRequest['quantity'];
            if ($qty > 0.0) {

                if ($itemFromDB == null || $itemFromDB->available == false)
                    return $this->error("Invalid item selected");

                $itemFromDB->quantity = $qty;
                $total += ($itemFromDB->sell_rate * $itemFromDB->quantity) / $itemFromDB->rate_unit_multiple;
                $cost += ($qty * $itemFromDB->purchase_rate) / $itemFromDB->rate_unit_multiple;
                array_push($itemList, $itemFromDB);
            }
        }
        if (count($itemList) == 0) {
            return $this->error("At least 1 item is needed to place the order");
        }
        // check user balance 
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
        // if balance < total -> throw error    
        if ($cod != true &&  $user->balance < $total) return $this->error("Insufficient Balance. Please recharge your wallet or use C.O.D.", 403);



        $order = new Order();
        $order->user_id = $user->id;
        $order->total = $total;
        $order->delivery_charge = $deliveryCharge;
        $order->purchase_rate = $cost;

        // because in-case user changes his/her name in future - the order should have the historical name & number
        $order->customer_name = $user->name;
        $order->customer_contact = $user->contact_no;
        $order->address_id = $addressId;

        if ($cod == true) {
            if ($useBalanceFirst == true) {
                if ($user->balance < $order->total)
                    $order->amount_due = $order->total - $user->balance;
                else
                    $order->amount_due = 0;
            } else {
                $order->amount_due = $order->total;
            }
        } else
            $order->amount_due = 0;

        $ordertransaction = new OrderTimeLine();
        $ordertransaction->created_by = Auth::user()->id;



        DB::transaction(function () use ($order, $itemList, $user, $ordertransaction) {
            // insert 1 entry into orders
            $order->save();
            $order->refresh();
            $newOrderItemList = array();
            // insert N entries for Items 
            foreach ($itemList as $requestItem) {
                $item   = new OrderItem();
                $item->order_id = $order->id;
                $item->item_id = $requestItem->id;
                $item->item_name = $requestItem->name;
                $item->sell_rate = $requestItem->sell_rate;
                $item->purchase_rate = $requestItem->purchase_rate;
                $item->quantity = $requestItem->quantity;
                $item->quantity_unit = $requestItem->unit;
                $item->rate_unit_multiple = $requestItem->rate_unit_multiple;

                if ($requestItem->remaining_stocks <= 0) {
                    $item->purchase_rate_qty = 0;
                } else if ($requestItem->remaining_stocks < $requestItem->quantity) {
                    $item->purchase_rate_qty = $requestItem->remaining_stocks;
                } else
                    $item->purchase_rate_qty = $requestItem->quantity;

                $item->save();
                $item->refresh();

                $requestItem->remaining_stocks = $requestItem->remaining_stocks - $requestItem->quantity;
                // update remaining QTY and cost price
                unset($requestItem->quantity);
                if ($requestItem->remaining_stocks <= $requestItem->alert_stocks) {
                    // send notification
                    NotificationController::notifyAdminAboutStocks($requestItem);
                }

                $requestItem->save();
                array_push($newOrderItemList, $item);
            }
            $order->items = $newOrderItemList;
            // deduct balance from user table
            $user->balance = $user->balance - $order->total + $order->amount_due;
            $user->save();
            $balanceAffected = 0 - $order->total + $order->amount_due;
            // enter transaction in wallet_transaction table   
            if ($balanceAffected != 0) {
                $transaction =  new WalletTransaction();
                $transaction->user_id = $user->id;
                $transaction->amount = $balanceAffected;
                $transaction->type = WALLET_ORDER_PLACED;
                $transaction->order_id = $order->id;
                $transaction->save();
            }

            $ordertransaction->status = $order->status;
            $ordertransaction->order_id = $order->id;
            $ordertransaction->save();
        });
        NotificationController::notifyAdminAboutOrder($user, $order);
        return $this->success(["balance" => $user->balance, "order" => $order]);
    }
```

Comment: First thing your function shouldn't be more than 20 lines.  and I'm not sure about your requirement but you can convert repetitive statements into unique function. their is also space for the eloquent relations in your model and use them

Comment: @Muhammad I want to do the exact same thing - make functions smaller - but there are no repetitive statements in this function. Also, for eloquent relations - Can those be used to insert and update as well? I know of relations only in select query

Comment: @Muhammad for the above function - can you please break it into smaller functions? Because I don't know how to break it into smaller ones.

Comment: You can break according the the functionalities, like if you are saving the order you can create a private saveOrder function() . transaction() etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling too many work in the controller function.
First of all I suggest to make full use of [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation) functionality. then use [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) to make your code more readable and compact. I have refactored your function as how I usually handle.

```
public function placeOrder(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->validate([
      'addressId' => 'required',
      'cod' => 'required|boolean',
      'useBalanceFirst' => 'required|boolean',
      'list' => 'required|array',
      'list.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric',
      'list.*.id' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::exists('items')->where(function ($query) {
          $query->where('available', true);
      })],
  ]);
  $user = Auth::user();
  $orderItems = collect($data['list'])->map(function($listItem){
      $item = Item::find($listItem['id']);
      $orderItem = new OrderItem([
          'item_id' => $item->id,
          'item_name' => $item->name,
          'sell_rate' => $item->sell_rate,
          'purchase_rate' => $item->purchase_rate,
          'quantity' => $listItem['quantity'],
          'quantity_unit' => $item->quantity_unit,
          'rate_unit_multiple' => $item->rate_unit_multiple,
      ]);
      if ($item->remaining_stocks <= 0) {
          $orderItem->purchase_rate_qty = 0;
      } else if ($item->remaining_stocks < $orderItem->quantity) {
          $orderItem->purchase_rate_qty = $item->remaining_stocks;
      } else
          $orderItem->purchase_rate_qty = $orderItem->quantity;

      return $orderItem;
  });
  $total =  $orderItems->sum(function($item){
      return ($item->sell_rate * $item->quantity) / $item->rate_unit_multiple;
  });
  $cost =  $orderItems->sum(function($item){
      return ($item->quantity * $item->purchase_rate) / $item->rate_unit_multiple;
  });

$deliveryCharge = Store::first()->delivery_charge;
  $total += $deliveryCharge;

  // if balance < total -> throw error
  if (!$data['cod'] && $user->balance < $total)
  {
      return $this->error("Insufficient Balance. Please recharge your wallet or use C.O.D.", 403);
  }

$order = new Order([
      'user_id' => $user->id,
      'total' => $total,
      'delivery_charge' => $deliveryCharge,
      'purchase_rate' => $cost,
      // because in-case user changes his/her name in future - the order should have the historical name & number
      'customer_name' => $user->name,
      'customer_contact' => $user->contact_no,
      'address_id' => $data['addressId'],
  ]);
  if ($data['cod']) {
      if ($data['useBalanceFirst']) {
          if ($user->balance < $order->total)
              $order->amount_due = $order->total - $user->balance;
          else
              $order->amount_due = 0;
      } else {
          $order->amount_due = $order->total;
      }
  } else
  {
      $order->amount_due = 0;
  }
  DB::transaction(function () use ($order, $orderItems, $user) {
      // insert 1 entry into orders
      $order->save();
      $order->items->saveMany($orderItems);
      // deduct balance from user table
      $user->balance = $user->balance - $order->total + $order->amount_due;
      $user->save();

    $ordertransaction = OrderTimeLine::create([
          'created_by' => $user->id,
          'status' => $order->status,
          'order_id' => $order->id,
      ]);
  });

  return $this->success(["balance" => $user->balance, "order" => $order]);
}
```

As you have noticed I have removed notification and user wallet transaction code as these should be updated asynchronously with no impact on your user experience.  I suggest you take a look at [Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for